# Number of orbits of the Frobenius automorphism

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields

Let $q=p^s$ be a prime power congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements, and let $\phi$ denote the Frobenius automorphism (that is $\phi(a)=a^p$ for every $a\in\mathbb{F}_q$).

Let $i$ be a primitive $4$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $P=\mathbb{F}^{\times}_q/\langle i\rangle =\left\{\{a,ia,-a,-ia\}\mid a\in\mathbb{F}^{\times}_q\right\}$. Since $i^p=\pm i$ (depending on whether $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ or $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$), the Frobenius automorphism acts on $P$.

**I am interested in the number of orbits of $\phi$ on $P$**.

There is a very nice, short [unpublished note](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~dmccullough/research/pdffiles/frobenius.pdf) by Gareth Jones, Darryl Mccullough and Marcus Wanderley in which the number of orbits of $\phi$ acting on $\mathbb{F}_q$ is computed using very basic ideas (the Cauchy-Frobenius-Burnside lemma + basic facts from finite field theory), an ideal answer for me would be in that spirit.

It is easy to directly compute this number in the case $q=p^2$, it is:

$\frac{p^2+2p-3}{8}$ for $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, and $\frac{p^2+4p-5}{8}$ for $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

Also, the case $q=p^k$, $k$ odd is easy (in this case we must have $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$) because we just divide by $4$ the number (minus $1$) computed in G. Jones et al.

I tried to figure out how to possibly combine the above results to obtain a general formula. No luck yet.

Comment: It seems to me that you have the group $G=C_4\rtimes C_k$ acting on $\Bbb{F}_q^*$. The generator of $C_4$ acts by multiplication by $i$, and the generator of $C_k$ acts by Frobenius. The product is direct, if $p\equiv1\pmod4$, because $i$ is then fixed by $\phi$, and semi-direct if $p\equiv3\pmod4$. Looks like you need to figure out the subgroups and tally their fixed points. Then apply Burnside-Frobenius to get the number of orbits.

Comment: @Jyrki, what is $k$ in your comment? The group acting is cyclic of order $s$.

Comment: Oops. I apparently picked $k$ from your next to large paragraph, and didn't look at the first line. It is of order $s$ anyway.

Comment: @Jyrki, I still do not understand what do you mean. Your group $G$ has order $4k$, while $s$ can be any positive integer (not necessarily a multiple of $4$).

Comment: I meant $G=C_4\rtimes C_s$. I thought that $q=p^k$. Sorry about not making that clear.